# Periodically seeing the ASP.NET error CS0656: Missing compiler required member

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I'm seeing the following error crop up occasionally (seemingly at random) on my web application.  We are running Windows Server 2008R2, IIS 7.5, MVC3, .NET 4.5.

[image: Compiler Error]

It's the same error every time: **CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.BinaryOperation'**

When this error occurs, it can take anything from a restart of the application pool, to the re-install of our application itself, to fix it.

The error occurs on brand-new VM images (no previous installation of our software), as well as machines that have previously had our software installed on it.  The error can occur upon the first run of the application, or when the application has sat long enough for the IIS application pool to recycle the worker process (so it seems).

This is becoming really difficult to deal with, as I've done a ton of research on this error, and tried multiple solutions, with no luck.  Also, the random frequency at which the error occurs has made it very hard to troubleshoot.  Any insight into this issue, or ideas on possible solutions, would be greatly appreciated.  I'm willing to try almost anything at this point.

Comment: 1) Can you attach a debugger one of your test VMs and make it crash? 2) Are you using the DLR? Looking through the BCL source and documentation, it appears that type name is associated with dynamic operations. Or perhaps it is MVC's use of the DLR?

Comment: Can you check what version of Microsoft.CSharp.dll is used (determine the path with a tool such as procexp), open it using a tool such as .NET Reflector and check the BinaryOperation static method is there? That may be a versioning issue (the compiler expects a more recent version of Microsoft.CSharp.dll)

Comment: Are you using C# Dynamic language features ? And anyway it looks like a CLR corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

This looks familiar. If I recall corectly I had to delete the bin directory and rebuild because older versions of dlls were floating around and this class was introduced in .net 4.0

After some research, this site seems to agree: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/20474-Missing-compiler-required-member-MicrosoftCSharpRuntimeBinderBinderInvokeMember

Answer (score 0):

**[Try *Forest Cheng* Answer:](http://forums.asp.net/t/1656827.aspx)**

What version your .NET Framework is?
The ASP.NET MVC 3 run-time components require .NET Framework version 4 and Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. Want more information, please look at [ASP.NET MVC 3 Release Notes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#installation-notes).

**Compiler Error CS0656 can be caused by the follow problems:**

1. Your installation of the common language runtime is corrupt.
2. You have a reference to an assembly that defines a type that is also found in the common language runtime. However, your assembly's type is not defined the way the C# compiler expects.

So check your references to ensure that you are using the correct version of the common language runtime.

Answer (score 0):

We used to have these compilation errors occuring randomly back in the day a long time ago with .net 1 and beyond.  This required deleting the contents of the temporary asp.net folder, and finding other rogue dlls that were hanging around, even inside a visual studio cache. In general, flushing the temporary asp.net folder will do it.

Make sure you find all the dlls - the bin folder too obviously, and remember that the dlls are executed from a shadow directory. That is why i recall (also from a long distant memory) that there is a connection to the default appdomain which assemblies are loaded into, especially if you then go loading "the same assembly " but from a different file location.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Microsoft.CSharp reference added in your project.

I added it to my test project and the error disappeared.